# Numerical root finding of a scalar function on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, numerical-calculus

I want to find roots of a $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$-function. The problem is that I can only find algorithms for $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$- and $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$-functions. I know very little about the roots, apart from that they are a $n-1$ dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I could also probably make some guesses of the whereabouts of a few.

**I will accept an answer that** either (a) provides a reference for the statement *that there are no root-finding methods for $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$-functions of the kind I am looking for* or (b) that provides a list of a few of the most popular ones or (c) a way I can adapt an existing method.

EDIT: Ideally I'd like to find as large parts of the manifold of zeros as possible, if there is some way to make that extension, please put it in the answer! Would be super helpful.

Comment: One problem is what you already mention: We cannot expect roots to be isolated, but they are manifolds. E.g., what would you expect from a "find the roots" algorithm for $x(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$? The zeroes form a circle. Do you want a single point on it? A point cloud of zeroes on the circle, in some sense "dense" on it? -- Of course, along any line in $\Bbb R^n$, you can use your $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ methods. And for "nearby" lines, you can even take the zeroes on the previous line as initial estimates ...

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to do is something along the lines of continuation, where you take an artificial "slice" of the solution set, determined by one or more parameters ($n-2$ parameters in your case), and that contains only finitely many points. Then you adjust the parameter and follow the solutions around. For a toy example you could trace the solutions to $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1=0$ by setting $x=a$, solving the system, and then varying $a$. Continuation algorithms find solutions with new values of the parameters more efficiently than solving the system from scratch again.

Comment: That said continuation is not really something that can be perfectly automated because of the possibility of bifurcations. Certain more sophisticated continuation algorithms can detect bifurcations (see for example the software package AUTO 07p) but this is a somewhat inexact science, prone to either missing bifurcations that actually exist or else detecting bifurcations that don't exist. And these issues get progressively worse in higher dimensions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If you update yourself on the rules of this website, you find out why I have to write it in this way. If you are able to contribute to the discussion, that would be appreciated.

Comment: @MikkelRev That's definitely not part of the rules here.

Comment: @Ian I cite «You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face». https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Yes, that doesn't mean you need to spell out your requirements for an answer, particularly not with such a demanding tone.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I feel bad about exactly one thing: I didn't notice that you _actually_ contributed to the question. That was a mistake on my part. I did start to read up on your marching cubes, and liked it a lot. I would like to apologise for that.

Answer (score 1):

Not for finding "roots", but for local/global minima/maxima there exist plenty of algorithms to find minima/maxima of functions. The most algorithms rely on the gradient descent method, which can be described as follows
$$ x_{n+1} := x_n - \gamma \nabla f(x_n) $$
where $\gamma>0$ is some (maybe adaptively updated) constant. 
Beware though: if your function has more local minima and a unique global minimum, it might happen that this finds just a local minimum. There are several upgrades to this algorithm to overcome this (stochastic gradient method, genetic algorithm etc.), but the choice highly depends on the problems itself.

Comment: I am not sure this is a valid answer. It seem the OP knows about this simple algorithm which is well known. The OP is after not trivial case (Even not well defined?).

Answer (score 0):

Check out methods that don't use derivatives (computing them can be very costly). E.g. Brent's ["Algorithms for minimization without derivatives"](https://doverpublications.com/0486419983.html) (Dover, 2003).